# How to get table(s) of contents listed in itself (themselves) with etoc package?

Tags: table-of-contents, etoc, tocbibind

**Update:** The version 1.2 (as of 2023-03-01) of `etoc` fixed with the deficiency subject of the current question.

**Update:** question precised and contextualized .

## Context

My real use case:

1. relies on many `etoc` features, among others multiple tables of contents,
2. needs table(s) of contents listed in themselves: I have 2 of them (easily achieved with `etoc`):

   - the 1st one (at the beginning of the document) being just an outline (not so deep),
   - the 2nd one (at the end of the document) being a detailed content (deeper).

Hence the 2<sup>nd</sup> TOC may be easily reached from the 1<sup>st</sup> one.

## Tested solution

An easy way to get a table of contents listed in itself is to use the `tocbibind` package. The trouble is, this package is incompatible with `etoc`. Indeed, as pointed out by the following examples:

- loading the former *before* the latter ruins the `tocbibind` features: the table of contents is not listed,
- loading the former *after* the latter ruins the `etoc` features: e.g. `\etocsetnexttocdepth` is ignored and only one TOC can be populated.

### `tocbibind` before `etoc`: former's features ruined (tables of contents not listed)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{etoc}
\begin{document}
\etocsetnexttocdepth{section}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection of a section}
\subsection{Another subsection of a section}
\section{Another section}
\subsection{A subsection of another section}
\subsection{Another subsection of another section}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

[image]

### `etoc` before `tocbibind`: former's features ruined (`\etocsetnexttocdepth` ignored and 2nd TOC empty)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\begin{document}
\etocsetnexttocdepth{section}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection of a section}
\subsection{Another subsection of a section}
\section{Another section}
\subsection{A subsection of another section}
\subsection{Another subsection of another section}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Question

I guess `etoc` package lets us display the table(s) of contents in table(s) of contents but how to do that (without the help of `tocbibind` which is incomptible)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `tocbibind` with `etoc` you need `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}`.

Apart from that, perhaps this kind of code can help in your exact context.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\etocsetnexttocdepth{section}
\tableofcontents
\etoctoccontentsline{section}{Table des mati\`eres initiales}
\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection of a section}
\subsection{Another subsection of a section}
\section{Another section}
\subsection{A subsection of another section}
\subsection{Another subsection of another section}
\tableofcontents
\etoctoccontentsline{section}{Table des mati\`eres finales}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I should have precised I tried `\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}` which doesn't solve my problem. I'm a bit disappointed: `etoc`, this very nice and powerful package, needs to manually add lines to the `.toc` file in order to get table(s) of contents listed in itself (themselves)? Too bad! ;)

Comment: there is indeed no such `etoc` option because the same document can use multiple `\tableofcontents` with completely different contexts and effect (see "Surprising uses of etoc" section in doc). On the other hand you have multiple possibilities to achieve it: as in my mwe, or using `\etocsettocstyle` to use a starred sectioning command and usual `\addcontentsline`, or to use `\etocaftertitlehook` ...  Idea is that `\etocsettocstyle` is more or less rather mandatory when dealing with sub-tocs, as, for example in book, you don't want them to use `\chapter` or `\chapter*`.

Answer (score 1):

After your edit, the finally interesting question is still unclear, at least to me.

My question would be, why do you want to include the line Table of Contents into the TOC?  What extra information could the reader gain on that extra line?  I'd say none.

Nevertheless, interpreting your code, it seems to me, as if you want to get rid of the subsections being displayed in the TOC.  If that assumption is correct, you could use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{N}` to exclude everything beyond level `N`.  In your case you need to choose `N` to be `1`.

Here is my suggestion

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\begin{document}

%% Prevent the \subsections from being displayed in the TOC
\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
\tableofcontents

\section{A section}
\subsection{A subsection of a section}
\subsection{Another subsection of a section}
\section{Another section}
\subsection{A subsection of another section}
\subsection{Another subsection of another section}
\end{document}
```

Resulting in

[image]

Comment: Having table(s) of contents listed in themselves may be useful e.g. if you have 2 of them (easily achieved with `etoc`), the 1st one (at the beginning of the document) being just an outline (not so deep), the 2nd one (at the end of the document) being a detailed content (deeper): hence the 2nd TOC may be easily reached from the 1st one. Furthermore, I know I can achieve `\etocsetnexttocdepth` without `etoc` and just with `\setcounter{tocdepth}` but this was just an example of the `etoc`'s features: my real case relies on many `etoc` other features (e.g. multiple tables of contents).

Comment: @DenisBitouzé, please add this important information to your MWE and postulate a real question as "how to achieve this or that".  It is important to be specific and clear, otherwise we only can guess.

Comment: My question appeared quite clear to me :) but, anyway, I attempted to clarify it.