# tocbibind package fails to add TOC to Contents, possible conflict with minitoc

Tags: etoc, tocbibind

I have the following LaTeX code for my thesis:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{ifthen}

\newlength\tocrulewidth
\setlength{\tocrulewidth}{1.5pt}

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
        \input{TitlePage.tex}
        \input{Declaration.tex}
        \input{Certificate.tex}
        \input{Dedication.tex}
        \input{Abstract.tex}
        \input{Acknowledgements.tex}        
        \tableofcontents        
        \listoftables
        \listoffigures
        \input{Publications.tex}

    \mainmatter
        \input{Chapter1/Chapter1.tex}
\end{document}
```

I include a mini-toc at the beginning of every chapter. Maybe that is why, I am not getting a "Contents" entry in the Contents. I get the following instead:

[image]

For the minitoc, I have the following code at each chapter:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
    \begingroup
        \parindent=0em
        \etocsettocstyle{\rule{\linewidth}{\tocrulewidth}\vskip0.5\baselineskip}{\rule{\linewidth}{\tocrulewidth}}
        \localtableofcontents 
    \endgroup

    % Text of the chapter goes here...
```

But I want a unnumbered "Contents" entry between "Acknowledgements" and "List of Tables". How can I do that? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I also found this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349419/how-to-get-tables-of-contents-listed-in-itself-themselves-with-etoc-package/349421 and so your question is a duplicate... You can ignore my answer and load tocbibind just after etoc... Tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First way:** You can try add it manually:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{tocbibind} Not needed now
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newlength\tocrulewidth
\setlength{\tocrulewidth}{1.5pt}





\begin{document}

    \frontmatter
    \chapter{Declaration}
    \chapter{Certificate}
        \tableofcontents\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Contents}
        \listoftables
        \listoffigures


    \mainmatter
        \chapter{test}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

**Second way:** Also you can use etoc to add it:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,multirow}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{tocbibind} Not need it!
\usepackage{etoc}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newlength\tocrulewidth
\setlength{\tocrulewidth}{1.5pt}





\begin{document}

    \frontmatter
    \chapter{Declaration}
    \chapter{Certificate}
        \tableofcontents\etoctoccontentsline{chapter}{Contents}
        \listoftables
        \listoffigures


    \mainmatter
        \chapter{test}
        \begingroup
        \parindent=0em
        \etocsettocstyle{\rule{\linewidth}{\tocrulewidth}\vskip0.5\baselineskip}{\rule{\linewidth}{\tocrulewidth}}
        \localtableofcontents 
        \endgroup
        \section{test section}
\end{document}
```

the result is the same.

I suppose tocbibind doesn't work with etoc.

Comment: Thank you, your method works. But, I also needed to include the tocbibind package, otherwise, the list of figures and list of tables disappear from the Contents.

Comment: Careful, although Contents does appear in the TOC, it has the wrong page number in my case. I have no idea why.

Comment: @konse .. we need more info on "your case" .. we also have no idea  why :P ...